# Native Page in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

I apologize in advance for my question, but I start with `Xamarin` and need help to create a particular architecture.

I should use Xamarin forms with MVVM Light , but with a large part of native pages (UWP).
For this, I wondered if I had to place my View-Models in the portable class or in the UWP Project ? And if in the portable class, what navigation use to navigate between my native pages ?

Answer (score 0):

The Logic should be placed inside the shared code so put your ViewModels inside the portable or shared project.

For navigation between pages you could use:

1. conditional compilation

   `if mobile 
   navigation droid/iOS 
   else
   navigation  UWP` 
   (Use with underscores, entering here is using formatting, see link
   [Condotional Compilation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_4_-_platform_divergence_abstraction_divergent_implementation/#Conditional_Compilation) for more details)
2. DependencyService as described here [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/introduction/)

I'm sure there are other ways but I think DependencyService is the most elegant, as those #if#else stuff makes the code confusing and unreadable.